# Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel compatible with CentOS?

Tags: oracle, centos

I'm installing Oracle 11.2. Anyone know if Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel ...

(1) is required to be installed for CentOS 5.5?

(2) may optionally be installed on CentOS 5.5?

I'm following the installation instructions and the way I interpret it is it's required. Looking for advice if it's required or optional, and if optional, do you recommend it?

Comment: I am 99% sure you don't need the Unbreakable Kernel. You can always try, the Universal Uninstaller will complain if you are trying to install it on an unsupported configuration.

Comment: If you're setting up a long-lived production installation for Oracle's table server, it is definitely worth your trouble to use a Linux distribution that's certified for that purpose.  Mix-and-match sometimes turns out to be mix-crash-mix-crash-match?-crash-match?  You get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly it isn't ( by design ). and in any case, as NullUserException points out, its not needed for oracle database.